# How to load javascript file in django templates

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

i want to make countdown timer in django website,for that i use javascript.but javascript file is not loading in templates(i also load css file which works fine)

countdown.js

```
alert('hello'):
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/countdown.js' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>

</body>
```

setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

Comment: Seems you are using `staticfile` (which is not *the best* to be place in production). You can try to see what `$ python manage.py findstatic js/countdown.js` and check if the filesystem matches what you/django are expecting.

Comment: C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Quiz>python manage.py findstatic js/countdown.js
Found 'js/countdown.js' here:
  C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Quiz\app\static\js\countdown.js

Comment: could change `staticfiles` with `static` and try again?

Comment: Yeah and can you tell which version of Django are you using? things changed pretty much between versions `<1.10` vs `<2.1` vs `>=2.1`.

Comment: @kamilyrb still no change

Comment: @zambotn my django version -  2.2.2

Comment: Have you see any errors in your console? Also could you load js files with <script> tag inside your body?

Comment: <script src="{% static 'js/countdown.js' %}"></script>

Comment: Is this correct

Comment: BTW if you use version above 2.1 you should use `{% load static %}` since `{% load staticfiles %}` has been deprecated (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#id2).

Comment: yes but you can add `type="text/javascript"` parameter

Comment: Still no change

Comment: How are you serving the static files? If it's served from your `STATIC_ROOT`, have you run `$ python manage.py collectstatic`? have you checked if the file does exists in `STATIC_ROOT` (path should be `C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Quiz\static\js\countdown.js`)?

Comment: Hey guys, js file is working now i dont how ,i just change js file name to app.js